# deploying react and django (server side) application on googlecloud

Tags: django, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I had created a web application.Front end is created by ReactJS and back-end(server side)is created by Django framework,

Here I am using PostgreSQL database.

The application is successfully running on my local machine by running both python `manage.py runserver` and `npm start` at a time in my terminal.

I need to deploy my entire app on google cloud using compute engine.

I already purchased a domain. I don't know how to connect these 2 platforms(Django and ReactJS) in cloud. if anyone knows deploy Django go as server-side and react as front-end in GooleCloud (using compute engine)

Comment: This question is very broad, and not necessarily Django related. You should at least try to do it yourself at first. Check out https://medium.com/@zackliutju/building-react-and-django-web-application-and-deploy-it-on-google-cloud-545f06eb5521

Answer (score 2):

Even though your question is a bit broad, I think you may find these resources useful:

- Getting started with Django [1]. You can compare the 4 main options to use Django in GCP.
- Django Certified by Bitnami [2] is a ready to use pre-configured Django environment that deploys all the Compute Engine resources you need.
- You can find more information on the Bitnami Django Stack For Google Cloud Platform here [3]

You could start using one of the pre-configured solutions and customize the VM by installing what you need afterwards. Or start with a blank VM and configure everything from scratch [4].

In a more general sense, this guide “Serving websites” [5] is a very good read to better understand all the options you have within Google Cloud Platform to host a website; more specifically, the section “Using virtual machines with Compute Engine” [6].

I’m assuming that you already know how to get Django and ReactJS work together, as you did it already in your local machine. I hope these articles are useful for you.

- [1]https://cloud.google.com/python/django/#hosting_platforms
- [2]https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/solution/bitnami-launchpad/djangostack?q=django
- [3]https://docs.bitnami.com/google/infrastructure/django/
- [4]https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance
- [5]https://cloud.google.com/solutions/web-serving-overview
- [6]https://cloud.google.com/solutions/web-serving-overview#compute-engine